# Full size content dialog uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create a content dialog with full width and height but i have a problem with set the width for all screen sizes and keep the button on the bottom

and Here's my code

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="app.Content_Dialog.WhatsNew"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:app.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"

x:Name="dialog2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  FullSizeDesired = "True" MaxWidth="600">

<Grid Height="800" Width="Auto">

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-24,0,0,165" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <!-- Take as much as needed -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <!-- Take exactly 20 DIP -->
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <!-- Take all the rest -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="close" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="close" Height="102" Width="374" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I'm trying to create something like this content dialog on MSPoweruser app

Here's a picture for it

[image]

Comment: @JustinXL read it again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't define a *Close* `Button` inside your content `Grid`, instead, use the `CloseButton` that's built within the `ContentDialog` itself.

So just remove the `Button` and the `Margin` on your `Grid`, and

*if you only target Windows 10 build `15063` and onward*

add `CloseButtonText="Close"` to your `ContentDialog`;

*if you target anything before `15063`*

add `SecondaryButtonText="Close"` instead.

If you want the `CloseButton` to take up the space horizontally, you need to apply a custom style to your `ContentDialog`, locate the container of the `Button`s and remove its column definitions.

Comment: How to change width and color for the button

Comment: There's also `CloseButtonStyle/SecondaryButtonStyle` available on `ContentDialog` for you to provide custom styling.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't find it? You just define it like `<ContentDialog SecondaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" ...` and then have your `MyButtonStyle` defined in your resource dictionary.

Comment: It's always giving there's nothing called SecondaryButtonStyle on content dialog control any help

Comment: Ohh looks like the style properties are only available in 15063, so you will need to go get the default style of the `ContentDialog` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx), locate the button and change its style there. It's called `Button2Host`.

Comment: Thanks for helping